# Drive not working with LSI controller

Tags: hardware-raid, lsi, netapp

I'm trying to use a NETAPP X412 drive (15K rpm 600GB) with LSI 9240-8i. The problem is that the drive shows up as 0 KB big, and attempting to set the drive to good fails with the error message "Operation not allowed." Other drives on the controller are working.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Drive info:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 30
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 20
WWN: 5000C5001D.....
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Logical Sector Size: 512 
Physical Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Device Firmware Level: NA03
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c5001d9.....
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: NETAPP  X412_S15K75.....           
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: Unknown 
Link Speed: Unknown 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

Storcli version: Ver 1.21.06 Nov 18, 2016

Controller firmware: 2.130.404-4659

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this without spending a lot more time than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

NetApp drives came with their very specific firmware, so it is quite possible that they are locked-down to work in NetApp appliances only.